# Live wallpaper that can set wallpaper to itself?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Some phones seem to not have livewallpaperpicker.apk.   Is there an API I can call from inside the app to set the live wallpaper to itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a phone does not have the live wallpaper picker, then this phone does not support live wallpapers.

Comment: Can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698266/can-i-change-live-wallpaper-programmatically-with-using-android-ndk-library

And 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683464/set-live-wallpaper-programmatically-and-skip-the-wallpaper-chooser